# Why are Jenkins related questions not suitable for ServerFault?

Tags: discussion

Recently I asked a Jenkins configuration question here on ServerFault, and it got migrated to StackOverflow (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35610719/is-there-a-way-to-separate-github-webhooks-in-three-categories-master-pull-req). I am confused becuse Jenkins is obviously a *server* (or perhaps I should call it a service), and from that perspective questions regarding jenkins are the same as questions regarding nginx, apache (httpd), postfix, dovecot, etc.

So, someone please explain the difference to me!

Comment: Jenkins CI is used mainly by DevOps, so it can be on-topic on the [DevOps proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/97295/devops), currently it's in Definition stage.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Basic configuration of a Jenkins server (e.g. installation, getting mail to work etc.) would be on topic here, but your question is about using it and then we get to the fact that Jenkins is a *development tool*, which is a topic for StackOverflow.

It can be a bit of a gray area, but I believe your question is quite clearly a "using a developer tool" type of question.

Comment: I intentionally did not post the question on StackOverflow because it is a SERVER CONFIGURATION question, not a development question... Apache httpd is a development tool as well, mariadb too, postfix can be as well (you can use it to send notifications to developers when some exception is thrown). We can find many use-cases when *any* server can be a development tool... But I get it, this site is actually "NotAllServerFault.com".

Comment: When I vote to close or migrate a question, I'm doing it as a favor.  You missed the target audience by posting it here.  If I realized everyone felt I was being mean to them when I did that, I wouldn't bother.  Just let the question sit unanswered.  Which would you prefer?

Answer (score 8):

From the [product description](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Meet+Jenkins) page:

> Jenkins is an award-winning, cross-platform, continuous integration and continuous delivery application that increases your productivity. Use Jenkins to **build and test your software projects continuously** making it easier **for developers** to integrate changes to the project, and making it easier for users to obtain a fresh build.

That makes questions about using Jenkins primarily a question about development tooling and although configuring Jenkins as a server is on-topic for ServerFault it is much **more suitable for StackOverflow**.
[stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) specifically lists *"software tools commonly used by programmers"* as on-topic.

If you look at the [jenkins](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/jenkins) tag usage on ServerFault you'll see 270 questions tagged compared to in excess of 14'000 on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jenkins), which seems to support that assumption.

Comment: And many of those 270 questions also probably should be on [so].