# Configuration management questions

Tags: feature-request, off-topic

Where do questions about ansible,  Jenkins,  puppet,  chef and others....belong?

I see them on stack overflow and server fault.

Comment: One of those things is not like the others....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Such things are generally in the overlap between our topicalities. You'll get answers on both, but they are considered topical here. [I've even asked them](https://serverfault.com/questions/349046/could-not-find-class-and-yet-it-is-there).

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't classify Jenkins as a configuration management tool.

[The ServerFault consensus](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/8648/why-are-jenkins-related-questions-not-suitable-for-serverfault) about Jenkins is that most question are about using it as development tooling  and therefore much more topical on Stack Overflow.